# checking if user exist in piranha cms mvc c#

Tags: asp.net-mvc, content-management-system, piranha-cms

I'm trying out Piranha Cms on MVC .net program. I want to allow external login, such as google, but before allow them to login, I want to check if user has existed in piranha Users profile, any idea how to check if user is existed in piranha users? Ideally something like GetUserByEmail or GetUserByName, like the one on user Identity of MVC .net.
I've been look at the source code of sysuser.cs but none of such method existed.

Thanks in advance for any clues/tips.

Answer (score 0):

The current version of Piranha CMS doesn't integrate with other authentications. This feature has however been planned for a couple of years but hasn't been implemented due to various reasons.